# OpenMQ and JMX - Is it possible to query for messages?

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx, openmq

I am able to query for queues by invoking a GET_DESTINATIONS operation using JMX. With that I will receive the queue info (attributes).
I would like now to query the messages that are stored in this queue, is that possible? Could someone give me some direction?

I have already tried using this code

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new
   com.sun.messaging.QueueConnectionFactory();


  Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  Queue myQueue = session.createQueue(string);

  QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(myQueue);
  Enumeration msgs = browser.getEnumeration();

  if (!msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
   System.out.println("No messages in queue");
  } else {
   while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
    Message tempMsg = (Message) msgs.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Message: " + tempMsg);
   }
  }

  connection.close();
```

But for some reason O can't access the same queue as using JMX. I didn't made any research on that because I want to use JMX as the access standard.

I am still trying to find any JMX operation that could help me, but I am not finding anything that could help me.

Could you please give me some hints what can I look for?

thank you,
Oscar

Edit: just to let you know: I don't want to consume the queues, I want a similar behavior to the Browser, in which I can read the messages without removing them from the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QueueBrowser browser = null;

try{
  Queue myQueue = session.createQueue(getName());

  //Create the browser and session to be able to iterate
  browser = session.createBrowser(myQueue);
  Enumeration msgs = browser.getEnumeration();
```

This code will give you the messages, then just iterate through it and you can get get infos about the message and its content